# Removing quintic plane from projective plane.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How to show that $P^2/X$, where $X$ is a plane quintic (i.e a curve of degree 5) is affine. Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

For any $d\geq 1$, one has a closed embedding $\mathbb{P}^2\subset\mathbb{P}^N$, where $N+1=\binom{d+2}{2}$, given by $\deg d$ homogeneous polynomials. If $F$ is any non-zero polynomial of degree $d$, this corresponds to a hyperplane $H$ in $\mathbb{P}^N$ and $\mathbb{P}^2-\{F=0\}=(\mathbb{P}^N-H)\cap\mathbb{P}^2$. But $\mathbb{P}^N-H=\mathbb{A}^N$ and thus $\mathbb{P}^2-\{F=0\}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{A}^N$ and thus affine.